# Are there any effective time management competitors to TSheets?

Tags: time-management

Our organization has been using TSheets for the last year, and we're not having a very good experience.

Staff run into issues with their App crashing regularly on both iOS and Android, on a range of devices. There have also been issues when calendars sync.

As such we're looking for a replacement. Time management/scheduling of staff hours is a must, and payroll integration is heavily appreciated (if this exists?).

Answer (score 0):

I've answered another question just like this one a couple of weeks ago.

We use [Deputy](https://www.deputy.com/) for the purposes that you've described, and it works well for us, on Android and Apple devices

We use it for payroll & scheduling, so it ticks your boxes.

Total cost is about four dollars per user per month.